# Interfacing to metal dome keyboard matrix PCB

Tags: pcb, connector

I have a project where I need to physically interface with a remote control keyboard matrix PCB to simulate key presses. Actually, this could be several different remote control PCBs we need to interface with, so we're just looking at this as a generic 8x8 matrix interface, and we'll customize configuration for each. As far as I can tell, all of these use metal domes for the buttons/keys. We've worked out the details of the electronics to connect rows to columns, but we're not exactly sure of the best way to actually interface to the PCB.

Options are:

1. Solder (or pogo pin?) to test points. However, not all of these will have test points for all of the keyboard matrix rows/columns
2. Solder (or pogo pin?) to vias. One board's test points are adequate, another has vias for both sides of each of the button switches, but still we're not sure if we'll find these on all boards.
3. Connect somehow to the conductive part on the PCBs under the metal domes. See picture below (found on Google). This isn't exactly how things look, but basically there's an inside and outside part of the switch, and pressing the dome connects it... *Note, per comment below. I think this is conductive ink; it doesn't look like something I could solder to.*

We're looking at doing only a few of these initially, but this could scale up a bit and be across multiple different remote controls, and we'd rather not have to hand solder wires for all of these.

How would you recommend making a permanent fixture for something like this? I'm wondering if it's possible to design and order a flex-type PCB that is adhesive that can just be stuck to the matrix in place of the metal dome array? Or anything like this at all? The boards have mounting holes, so we can use that for compression, if necessary.

[image]

Comment: is the surface finish under the domes like in the image you posted (i.e. HASL)? If it's silver, it's probably hasl, if its gold its enig, and if its conductive ink, it will be bumpy and black.

Comment: @BeB00 It's a matte black color, so I suppose conductive ink

Comment: you'll have trouble soldering then, you probably need to go with pogo pins or a similar solution